# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'customAuthenticationProvider' is defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills. Nowhere in my spring-security-context.xml do I refer to 'customAuthenticationProvider' shown in the stack trace below.

Can someone please help me spot my issue?

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app metadata-complete="true" version="3.0" id="pss"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<!-- other stuff -->

  <!-- Spring Security Configuration -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>  

<!-- other stuff -->

</web-app>
```

*spring-security-context.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/api/mobile/**" filters="sif,customMobileSecurityFilter"/>
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/admin/**" filters="sif,customAdminSecurityFilter"/>
        </sec:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sif" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter"/>

    <bean id="customMobileSecurityFilter" class="com.server.webapp.CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="customAuthenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
        <property name="postOnly" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="customAdminSecurityFilter" class="com.server.webapp.CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="customAuthenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
        <property name="postOnly" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="customAuthenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" />
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider"/>
</beans>
```

*The stacktrace*

```
2014-07-07 17:31:05 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#170db745' of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#170db745': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customAuthenticationProvider' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'customAuthenticationProvider' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_17]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the customAuthenticationProvider an @Autowired or @Resource() annotated class within your customAuthenticationManager? It is obviously being referenced somewhere so those are the first things that come to mind.

Comment: Nope, I had no annotations, but you're definitely on the right track. I will post the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out with the help of one of my colleagues. Rookie mistake.

The tomcat (web.xml) and spring security (spring-security-context.xml) configuration files I was changing are maintained in our /web/WEB-INF/ folders.

However, I didn't realize prior to deployment that our ant build scripts place everything tomcat related in /build/. Specifically, web.xml and spring-security-context.xml get copied into /build/WEB-INF/.

I was not running the ant build scripts prior to redeploying tomcat, and so the older versions of the configuration files were being used, which referenced customAuthenticationProvider.

After figuring that out, I also came to realize I was missing a definition of my customAuthenticationSuccessHandler bean, and was not defining a UserDetailsService for my AuthenticationProvider in spring-security-context.xml.

Below is the corrected version:

*spring-security-context.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/api/mobile/**" filters="sif,customMobileSecurityFilter"/>
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/admin/**" filters="sif,customAdminSecurityFilter"/>
        </sec:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sif" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter"/>

    <bean id="customMobileSecurityFilter" class="com.server.webapp.CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="customAuthenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="customAdminSecurityFilter" class="com.server.webapp.CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="customAuthenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.server.webapp.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="customAuthenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" />
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="customPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="customPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService"/>
</beans>
```